# How to select only links without `#`?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink

I want to select only links that do not contain anchors, like `#`. How do I do that?

Comment: please provide some kind of example (preferably several).  They're getting down vote happy down there!

Comment: please be more specific as to which cases you're trying to select. Are you after links where the anchor is not `#` or `""` or are you trying to exclude hashtags in general?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code:

If you want to filter href="#":

```
$('a[href!="#"]')
```

Otherwise:

```
$('a').filter(function(){
    return !/#/.test(this.href);//you can filter what you do not want with the regex
})
```

Comment: "contains" != "exists only of"

Comment: -1 Unfortunately this does not work - this will only work if the entire `href` is `"#"` not if it contains any.

Comment: -1 for a custom filter for what's already covered with jQuery's selectors.

Answer (score 3):

This will select all anchors whose href attribute does not begin with `#`.

```
$('a:not([href^="#"]');
```

It could be a slow selector. Are you using it only once or multiple times? You can speed it up a little like:

```
$('a').not('[href^="#"]');
```

If you also do not want to select anchors which contain a `#`anywhere, rather than just the beginning you can change the `^` to a `*`. But this will also not select links that reload the browser (going to a different page and then to a named anchor on that page). I don't think that's want you want, but I'm not positive now.

Comment: there we go... may need quotes but it's got my +1 anyhow

Comment: @PaulPRO: read the question again. `href="blalba/#mylink"` would be matched for example.

Comment: @chelmertz ... dude... the poster said *"anchors, like #"*. Thus some of us assume he only wants anchors that are acting like anchors and not links.

Comment: @Joseph: "do not contain anchors". End of discussion, I'm out. -1

Comment: @zzzBov, I think he wants to select links like that. Since it reloads the browser it is not *just* a named anchor. I'm pretty sure he only doesn't want to select links that begin with '#'

Comment: @chel I edited my post to be more clear now, so the OP can decide what he wants.

Answer (score 2):

<del>Try this:</del>

```
$(':not(a[href*="#"]));
```

---

This will be faster (and will select only anchors as well):

```
$('a:not([href*="#"])');
```

Comment: As is it selects everything that isn't an anchor as well.

Comment: This isn't a good approach. It needs to apply the filter to *every* element on the page instead of just `a` elements. EDIT: Answer has been fixed.

Answer (score 2):

I'm so surprised by all the fast answers, as most of them don't actually do what was asked for.

```
$('a:not([href*="#"])');
```

Should select links that don't contain "anchors" or as I assume OP meant: in-page anchor/id tags.